# What does the part a[a[i-1] of this for loop mean?

Tags: arrays, for-loop

I'm new in programming and my test is going to be soon, but I have no idea what happens in this for loop. Could someone explain it to my.
I'd be very thankful :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVN8p.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: you didn't even tell us (through a tag) which programming language this is supposed to be! Also, make sure to just copy and paste the program code. Pictures of text exclude just too many users and make it impossible to just copy&paste for searching and testing.

Comment: and: you haven't shown us any attempt. We really can't guess where you're stuck. So, this is just impossible to answer as is.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing fancy. It's just a simple for loop with some compound statements. let me explain every bit of it.

The syntax ( writing sequence ) of for loop is below.

```
for(initial value for loop ; condition to check on every loop ; increment in initial value)
{
  body of loop
}
```

**First Line** :

```
int[] a = new int[6];
```

This line is only declaring an INTEGER ARRAY of length 6

**Second Line** :

```
for(int i=0; i<=10 ; i=i+2) a[i/2] = i < 5 ? 5 - i : 0 ;
```

This is a compound statement, First simplify this.

The above CODE can be written as

```
for (int i=0 ; i<=10 ;i=i+2)
{
 if(i < 5)
  {
     a[i/2] = 5 - i;
  }
  else
  {
    a[i/2] = 0;
  }
}
```

**Third Line** :

```
for(int i=a.length ; i > 0 ; i--) a[i-1] = a[a[i-1]] + i ;
```

The above code can be written as followed

```
for(int i = a.length ; i > 0 ; i-- )
{ 
  //decomposing a[a[i-1]]

  //lets assume that **i = 2** and **a[1] = 99**;
  a[ value of a[i-1] which is a[2-1] => a[1] which is 99 ];
 // so after putting value of a[1] the above equ will be

  a[99]
  //this is also be equal to some value, let say a[99] == 40;
  //then 
  
  a[i-1] = 40 + i;

  
  
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but I thought that a[4]=a[4]+5=9...but why is the answer 10?

Comment: `a = [5,3,1,0,0,0]` final array and for a[a[4]], as a[4] value is 0, so it will be a[0]. and then we check for the value a[0] and that is 5. now a[a[4]] => 5 . Finally 5+5 = 10.

Comment: bro, you are my hero, thanks a lot :)